# How to "escape early" in a web monad

Tags: haskell

Something that happens to me a lot while web programming: I want to run an operation that has a chance of failure. On a failure, I want to send the client a 500. Normally though, I just want to continue executing a series of steps.

```
doSomeWebStuff :: SomeWebMonad ()
doSomeWebStuff = do
    res <- databaseCall
    case res of 
        Left err -> status 500
        Right val -> do
             res2 <- anotherDatabaseCall (someprop val)
             case res2 of 
                 Left err -> status 500
                 Right val2 -> text $ show val2
```

since the errs are exceptions, I don't like that I need all that case stuff just to catch them. I want to do the same thing whenever anything is a left. Is there a way to express that on one line with something like `guard`, but control what it returns on an exit?

In another language I could do this:

```
function doSomeWebStuff() {
    var res = databaseCall()
    if (res == Error) return status 500
    var res2 = anotherDatabaseCall(res.someprop)
    if (res2 == Error) return status 500
    return text(res2)
}
```

So, I'm ok writing some boilerplate, but I don't want the errors to mess with my nesting, when it's far more common to just want to continue forward with the found case.

What's the cleanest way to do this? I know in theory I can use a monad to exit early on a failure, but I've only seen examples with `Maybe` and it would return `Nothing` at the end, rather than letting me specify what it returns.

Comment: A beautiful example of why Monad laws are useful :)

Comment: The `Either` monad can be used for early exit with a return value (`Left`).

Comment: @shang Nowadays `Either e`'s `fail` is `error`, that's likely to give a few unwanted effects. I recommend looking at `ErrorT`.

Comment: I'm too much of a beginner in Haskell to give a proper answer, but when you `msum` your actions, you get exactly that - if any of them becomes `Left`, the error cascades, else it continues. So no need of explicit checks, further actions won't be executed if the previous is `Left`.

Comment: I'm a beginner, so I still need a little hand-holding when it comes to combining monads. Part of the issue with this problem is that I'm already in a web monad. I'll check out what you've mentioned, but I'm  slow, so I'd appreciate examples! Thanks!

Comment: The `somethingT` are Monad Transformers, they combine different monads to give you the combined effect. Take a look here - http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads (by the way, you should really read the whole thing... it's long, but useful)

Comment: Excellent `ErrorT` teaching opportunity aside, it seems like rather bad form to just give up and send the client a 500 error when bad stuff happens.

Comment: @Dan - The real pattern I use in other languages is to send a 500 with an error message, for debugging. I can change the way 500s are handled with middleware. What would you do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would do it with `ErrorT`. Disclaimer: I have never actually used `ErrorT` before.

```
webStuffOr500 :: ErrorT String SomeWebMonad () -> SomeWebMonad ()
webStuffOr500 action = do
  res <- runErrorT action
  case res of
    Left err -> do
      logError err -- you probably want to know what went wrong
      status 500
    Right () -> return ()

doSomeWebStuff :: SomeWebMonad ()
doSomeWebStuff = webStuffOr500 doSomeWebStuff'

doSomeWebStuff' :: ErrorT String SomeWebMonad ()
doSomeWebStuff' = do
    val <- ErrorT databaseCall
    val2 <- ErrorT $ anotherDatabaseCall (someprop val)
    lift $ text $ show val2
```

Here are the imports and type declarations I used to make sure it all typechecks correctly:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad

type SomeWebMonad = Identity

data Foo = Foo
data Bar = Bar
data Baz = Baz deriving (Show)

someprop :: Foo -> Bar
someprop = undefined
databaseCall :: SomeWebMonad (Either String Foo)
databaseCall = undefined
anotherDatabaseCall :: Bar -> SomeWebMonad (Either String Baz)
anotherDatabaseCall = undefined
logError :: String -> SomeWebMonad ()
logError = undefined
text :: String -> SomeWebMonad ()
text = undefined
status :: Int -> SomeWebMonad ()
status = undefined
```

If I'm doing this all wrong then please, somebody shout out. It may be wise, if you take this approach, to modify the type signature of `databaseCall` and `anotherDatabaseCall` to also use `ErrorT`, that way `a <- ErrorT b` can be reduced to `a <- b` in `doSomeWebStuff'`.

Since I'm a complete noob at `ErrorT`, I can't really do any hand-holding besides "here's some code, go have some fun".

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered using [Snap](http://snapframework.com/)? In snap, we have short-circuiting behavior built-in with an idiomatic:

```
getResponse >>= finishWith
```

where

```
finishWith ::  MonadSnap m => Response -> m a
```

So given a response object, it will terminate early (and match whatever type comes after that). Haskell laziness will ensure computations within Snap monad after finishWith won't be executed.

I sometimes make a little helper:

```
finishEarly code str = do
  modifyResponse $ setResponseStatus code str
  modifyResponse $ addHeader "Content-Type" "text/plain"
  writeBS str
  getResponse >>= finishWith
```

which I can then use anywhere in my handlers.

```
myHandler = do
  x <- doSomething
  when (x == blah) $ finishEarly 400 "That doesn't work!!"
  doOtherStuff
```

Comment: +1 certainly relevant; I was going to mention in my answer that major web framework monads probably have some form of ErrorT built in, but I'm not familiar enough with any to substantiate that claim like you have.

Comment: I'm using scotty, and indeed it does have a finishEarly-like construct